# Suggested select list design for 30-list item that will grow by 4 items per year

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to decide which SELECT widget/configuration to use (probably JQuery, since that's our standard) for a list of semesters. Currently there are 30, but the list will grow by four each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a SELECT with OPTGROUPS for the years and OPTIONS for semesters within each year. I would also probably put the current year at the top if that matches expected usage, i.e. reverse ordering of years.

But, as the other posters have noted, I wouldn't let this get too big. More than about a dozen selection items are just irritating and hard to use. If you already have 7 years' worth it might be better to have a SELECT/OPTIONS or a spinner for the year and then a separate SELECT/OPTIONS or a set of radiobuttons for the semester within the year.

I don't see what JQuery has to do with this question.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. I am *talking* about how it will look.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is what you use as a standard, I would stick with what you already use. Both for a unity in use for your users, and to save any poor developers who end up with their hands on the code at a later date the headaches of figuring out what library you used for what functionality.

Even still, this could become a rather massive select box. Eventually you may want to extract it to an overlay window with a list-box for selection. Because, frankly, massive select lists can be very confusing

Comment: I guess I'm asking what control to use, though your idea of having a modal pop with a list of semesters might just be the thing.